# Struggling with mini ammeter on power supply

Tags: power-supply, current-measurement

bit of a beginner here so please go easy on me.

I have a power supply (DC 24V30A) that I use to power a battery charger and soldering iron as well as a couple of other things (not all at once). It was a bit untidy so I designed and had printed a 3D case for it. At first I just ran the positive and negative into a couple of banana connectors so that I could easily swap between loads but I also thought it would be cool to put in a mini ammeter to monitor amp draw (purely a novelty thing, I don't need it, I just think it looks cool), however I'm having some issues getting it to work.

This is the ammeter I bought, its 0-30V 0-50A.

[image]

And this is the wiring diagram that was on the items page when I ordered it..

[image]

I've tried wiring it exactly like this. With no load connected the ammeter reads 12.4 (If anyone can explain this I'd really appreciate it. I don't understand how it has a reading at all when the circuit it technically broken? Unless its shorting from the thin red?). With a load connected it reads zero and the load doesn't power.

I tried a few different things incase the wires were labelled wrong, the only way I could get the load to power was by reversing the thick white and black and also connecting the thin black ground but the ammeter reading was zero again.

Hopefully what's happening is obvious to someone more knowledgeable on the subject and you'll tell me I'm an idiot for getting it wrong :) Otherwise I can't work out what's happening so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but questions on the *usage* of products are not on topic here, doubly so when they are dodgy e-commerce items of mystery origin and next to no documentation.  Just looking at it, that device is not suited for anywhere near 50 amps.  It also looks like someone may have cheaped out and omitted the sense resistor, or maybe tried to fake it with some PCB foil instead.

Comment: Really you are better off leaving this out of your system.  If you want current metering, either get something hall-based, or get a trustworthy shunt, wire that as a permanent part of your system not adding extra lead length, and then tap the meter in to measure the voltage across the shunt.  If you care to reverse engineer the current gizmo you might even be able to use it for such monitoring.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks! Sounds like its a crappy component then and not my wiring? I'll forget about it then :)

Comment: I suspect that the two rectangular solder pads below the display should have a shunt resistor (very low value resistor) between them - the meter will measure the voltage across the shunt to determine the current drawn by the load.